# How do I link a primary data set to a secondary data set with javascript?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to extend a primary object with elements that I'll look-up from a second object.

The primary collection looks like this:

```
collection1 = [
    {"user":"user1", "category":"cat1", "item":"item2"},
    {"user":"user2", "category":"cat2", "item":"item4"}
];
```

The secondary collection looks like this:

```
collection2 = {
    "dateStamp":"2016-12-23",
    "details":[
        {"category":"cat1", "item":"item1", "attribute":"1"},
        {"category":"cat1", "item":"item2", "attribute":"2"},
        {"category":"cat2", "item":"item3", "attribute":"1"},
        {"category":"cat2", "item":"item2", "attribute":"2"},
        {"category":"cat2", "item":"item4", "attribute":"3"}
    ]
};
```

I would like the final result to look like this:

```
collection3 = [
    {"user":"user1", "category":"cat1", "item":"item2", "dt":"2016-12-23", "attribute":"2"},
    {"user":"user2", "category":"cat2", "item":"item4", "dt":"2016-12-23", "attribute":"3"}
];
```

I was thinking to scroll-through collection1 and, for each record, look up the attribute value in collection2. However, I haven't gotten it to work; currently failing on the lookup (find) method. I'm clearly misusing it. :)

The following code fails on the commented line:

```
var collection1 = [
    {"user":"user1", "category":"cat1", "item":"item2"},
    {"user":"user2", "category":"cat2", "item":"item4"}
];

var collection2 = {
    "dateStamp":"2016-12-23",
    "details":[
        {"category":"cat1", "item":"item1", "attribute":"1"},
        {"category":"cat1", "item":"item2", "attribute":"2"},
        {"category":"cat2", "item":"item3", "attribute":"1"},
        {"category":"cat2", "item":"item2", "attribute":"2"},
        {"category":"cat2", "item":"item4", "attribute":"3"}
    ]
};

var collection3 = [];

collection1.forEach(function(c){
    c.dateStamp = collection2.dateStamp;
    //c.attribute = collection2.find({"details.category":c.category, "details.item":c.item});
    collection3.push(c);
});

console.log(collection3);
```

And I was also thinking a SQL-like "join" would be more efficient... but not sure it's possible with this data.

Can someone provide a working example and/or guidance on the most elegant way to handle this use case? Thank you!

Comment: please provide code that shows an attempt to get this to work. You've said it yourself that you "...haven't gotten it to work." - please share code.

Comment: What you have are JavaScript objects and arrays, not JSON. JSON is a **textual**, language independent data format. You have JavaScript code.

Comment: Thanks, Felix. I appreciate the clarification. Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simpler solution to your problem.

## ES6

Using the `Array#find` method (beware it's not supported on IE but you can use [Babel](https://babeljs.io/) or a [standalone polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find#Polyfill)) you can find the data you need from `collection2.details`.

```js
var collection1 = [
    {"user":"user1", "category":"cat1", "item":"item2"},
    {"user":"user2", "category":"cat2", "item":"item4"}
];

var collection2 = {
    "dateStamp":"2016-12-23",
    "details":[
        {"category":"cat1", "item":"item1", "attribute":"1"},
        {"category":"cat1", "item":"item2", "attribute":"2"},
        {"category":"cat2", "item":"item3", "attribute":"1"},
        {"category":"cat2", "item":"item2", "attribute":"2"},
        {"category":"cat2", "item":"item4", "attribute":"3"}
    ]
};

var collection3 = collection1.map((c) => {
  c.dateStamp = collection2.dateStamp;
  c.attribute = collection2.details.find((detail) => {
    return detail.category === c.category && detail.item === c.item;
  }).attribute;
  return c;
});

console.log(collection3);
```

## ES5

For a more conservative browser support approach, you can use this version:

```js
var collection1 = [
  {"user":"user1", "category":"cat1", "item":"item2"},
  {"user":"user2", "category":"cat2", "item":"item4"}
];

var collection2 = {
  "dateStamp":"2016-12-23",
  "details":[
    {"category":"cat1", "item":"item1", "attribute":"1"},
    {"category":"cat1", "item":"item2", "attribute":"2"},
    {"category":"cat2", "item":"item3", "attribute":"1"},
    {"category":"cat2", "item":"item2", "attribute":"2"},
    {"category":"cat2", "item":"item4", "attribute":"3"}
  ]
};

var collection3 = collection1.map(function(c) {
    var detail;
    c.dateStamp = collection2.dateStamp;
    for (var i = 0; i < collection2.details.length; i++) {
        detail = collection2.details[i];
        if (detail.category === c.category && detail.item === c.item) {
          c.attribute = detail.attribute;
          break;
        }
    }
    return c;
});

console.log(collection3);
```

You will also notice that in both versions I replaced your `Array#forEach` call with an `Array#map` call since it's cleaner what the intention the code is, to generate a new array from `collection1`.

Comment: This is great -- thanks! I like the map so I don't have to iterate. What about using filter() instead of find()? Any pros or cons there? I'll refactor my solution tomorrow based on your example. Thanks, again!

Comment: Brilliant. Tests perfectly and is very easy to understand. `Array#map` is elegant, as is `Array#find`. You win! :)

Comment: Glad you like the solution!

Answer (score 1):

Just in time before christmas, hope this helps:

```js
collection1 = [
        {"user":"user1", "category":"cat1", "item":"item2"},
        {"user":"user2", "category":"cat2", "item":"item4"}
    ];
    
    collection2 = {
        "dateStamp":"2016-12-23",
        "details":[
            {"category":"cat1", "item":"item1", "attribute":"1"},
            {"category":"cat1", "item":"item2", "attribute":"2"},
            {"category":"cat2", "item":"item3", "attribute":"1"},
            {"category":"cat2", "item":"item2", "attribute":"2"},
            {"category":"cat2", "item":"item4", "attribute":"3"}
        ]
    };
    
    function mergeObjects(obj1,obj2){
        var obj3 = {};
        for (var attrname in obj1) { obj3[attrname] = obj1[attrname]; }
        for (var attrname in obj2) { obj3[attrname] = obj2[attrname]; }
        return obj3;
    }
    
    function compare(obj,array){
      var foundIndex = -1;
      var maxCount = 0;
      for(var index=0; index < array.length; index++){
        var count = 0;
        for(var prop in obj){
          if(obj[prop] === array[index][prop]){
            count++;
          }
        }
        if(count>maxCount){
          maxCount = count;
          foundIndex = index;
        }
      }
      return array[foundIndex];
    }
    
    var collection3  = [];
    for(var col1=0; col1 < collection1.length; col1++){
      
      // search in  collection2['details'] for each equal collection1 element 
      var coll2Result = compare(collection1[col1],collection2['details']);
      
      // build a element for collection3
      var mergeObj = mergeObjects(collection1[col1], coll2Result);
      mergeObj = mergeObjects(mergeObj, {dt: collection2['dateStamp']});
      
      collection3.push(mergeObj);
    }
    
    console.log(collection3);
```

Comment: This works. Thanks! I'm going to mark @gaetanoM with the answer, however, as it seems more elegant to me. Very much appreciated!

Comment: It turns out the other solution was "too elegant" :). It doesn't work as desired. Your solution, however, does! Happy holidays.

Answer (score 0):

Using [Array.prototype.forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) it's possible to count the number of elements in collection2.details grouped by category.

After with [Array.prototype.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) it's possible to produce the final result:

```js
var collection1 = [
  {"user":"user1", "category":"cat1", "item":"item2"},
  {"user":"user2", "category":"cat2", "item":"item4"}
];
var collection2 = {
  "dateStamp":"2016-12-23",
  "details":[
    {"category":"cat1", "item":"item1", "attribute":"1"},
    {"category":"cat1", "item":"item2", "attribute":"2"},
    {"category":"cat2", "item":"item3", "attribute":"1"},
    {"category":"cat2", "item":"item2", "attribute":"2"},
    {"category":"cat2", "item":"item4", "attribute":"3"}
  ]
};


var hwc2 = {};
collection2.details.forEach(function(ele) {
  hwc2[ele.category] = (hwc2[ele.category] === undefined) ? 1 : hwc2[ele.category] + 1;
});


var collection3  = collection1.map(function(val, idx) {
  var retVal = val;
  retVal['dt'] = collection2.dateStamp;
  retVal['attribute'] = hwc2[val.category];
  return retVal;
});

console.log(collection3);
```

Comment: Excellent solution. Thank you! It seems very elegant to me. Cheers!

Comment: Actually... upon further testing this does not work. It appears to be returning the count of items within the category. The intended result is to match both the category and item and return the attribute. The initial test worked because the "match" was the last item. When the "match" is not the last item the returned attribute is incorrect.